# Does vim's ex command line support (readline-like) motions?

Tags: cursor-motions, ex-mode

## tldr

Moving in ex command line is slow because common readline motions (like in bash) are not supported. Are there any improvements for this?

---

I often find myself with an ex command in the command line and the need to e.g. edit something at the very beginning. For instance, I may have entered ex mode and pressed <kbd>↑</kbd> to repeat the last ex command. I then have

```
:e src/Sensors/Camera/SimulatedCameraSensor.cpp|
```

in the command line, with `|` being the cursor. In readline-enabled programms, I could use <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> or <kbd>Alt- ←</kbd> to quickly move to the beginning of the line, but in vim I seem to have to press the left arrow and move over individual characters.

Is there any configuration or are there any shortcuts which will speed up cursor motions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found two workarounds:

1. [This plugin](https://github.com/ryvnf/readline.vim) adds some readline motions to command mode
2. As outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189573/2397253), one can press Ctrl-f in command mode to make the current command editable like in normal mode. This is incompatible with the option 1.

Comment: Since we’re doing plugins: https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi

Answer (score 2):

I’ll add my most common alternatives:

- Use the default `:`-editing bindings (`:help commandline-editing` or something similar, if anyone has the reference offhand feel free to edit). `<C-b>` is beginning, `<C-e>` is end, and there are others
- Use the wonderful `<C-f>` if you started a `:`, `?`, or `/` and want to edit like it’s a normal vim buffer.
- Use `q:`, `q?`, or `q/` if you know you need this when you start.

I have `<leader>;` mapped to `q:` so a vim-edited command-line is very quick access. (I prefer not to switch `;` and `:` in my everyday editing, but I’m considering it.)